# Garbage collection of local instance that calls a method that performs asynchronous tasks

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, garbage-collection

If I have a local instance of class that calls a method that performs asynchronous tasks, can I depend on garbage collection never being performed before the asynchronous tasks are completed. Here is an example of what I am referring to; if I have the following:

```
private void loadDocument(String url) {
    HtmlReader reader = new HtmlReader();
    reader.addHtmlListener(this);
    reader.loadUrl(url);            
}
```

and the code for `HtmlReader` looks like this:

```
public class HtmlReader {

    ArrayList<HtmlListener> _htmlListeners = new ArrayList<HtmlListener>();

    public void addHtmlListener(HtmlListener listener) {
        this._htmlListeners.add(listener);      
    }

    public void removeHtmlListener(HtmlListener listener) {
        this._htmlListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void processHtmlResponse(String url, String html) {  
        for (HtmlListener listener: this._htmlListeners) {
            listener.loadUrlSuccessCallback(url, html);
        }       
    }

    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        new GetHtmlTask().execute(url);
    }

    class GetHtmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            ....
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
            processHtmlResponse(html);
        }
    }

    public interface HtmlListener {
        void loadUrlSuccessCallback(String url, String html);
    }
}
```

Given this scenario, the `loadDocument` method will definitely complete before the asynchronous task is completed. Can I be certain that the `reader` instance will not be garbage collected until after the `GetHtmlTask` has completed?

Comment: Does reader.addHtmlListener put a reference to the listener in a collection maintained by reader?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the because the reader can be accessed from the active thread for the AsyncTask, it won't become eligible for Garbage collection.  If you're worried, (or you've experienced some issue that leads you to believe otherwise) then you can just add explicit references to the reader in the AsyncTask (the GetHthmlTask).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I have completed the code for HtmlReader

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan It is not so much a case of being worried as wanting to understand how garbage collection would work in this situation. I could also make the `reader` local variable a member variable of the class, but I prefer not using member variables where they are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetHtmlTask` will not be garbage collected while there is a reference to it. The scheduler maintains such a reference as long as the thread is alive. Because it, in turn, is an inner class of your `HtmlReader` class, it maintains a reference to its enclosing instance. Therefore, the instance will not be garbage collected as long as the task is running.

Answer (score 1):

What I know about garbage collection is that, Garbage collection occurs only when objects goes out of scope and objects have no live references pointing to them. In your case, I think reader object will not be garbage collected since, asynchronous task is spawned by the reader instance is still active. Once every single object spawned by reader object is out of scope only then it will be garbage collected.

More about [Garbage Collection](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) in java.